# Windows server r2 2012 VPS, FTP login fail using File Zilla

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012-r2, filezilla

I am trying to login with FTP account on windows server vps hosting but in FileZill
giving me response

> Response: 530 User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP user you're logging in don't have the access to the FTP site then this error will happen. So that check your credentials to connect with the FTP. For testing try to allow anonymous login and restart the FTP site and then connect to FTP via FileZilla.